# Regular MVC routes are treated as REST routes

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a simple controller named AjaxController,

```
<?php
    class AjaxController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {
        $params = $this->_getAllParams();
        Zend_Debug::dump($params);
    }

    public function cartAction() {
        $params = $this->_getAllParams();
        Zend_Debug::dump($params);
    }
}

?>
```

And I am calling this URL - http://example.com/ajax/cart from jQuery like below:

```
$.post(base_path + "ajax/cart/", { },
 function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });
```

I get a 404 error (Action not found) when called via jQuery/When I visit the URL directly

I get the following output alone (for the init function):

```
array(4) {
  ["controller"] => string(4) "ajax"
  ["action"] => string(3) "get"
  ["id"] => string(4) "cart"
  ["module"] => string(7) "default"
}
```

Here action is "get" and "cart" goes into ID (Just like a Zend Rest Route). Instead, the action name should be "cart". What is wrong here?

The route works expected, if I add the following route via a ini file:

```
routes.about.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.about.route = "ajax/cart"
routes.about.defaults.controller = "ajax"
routes.about.defaults.action = "cart"
```

But I cannot add routes like this for **all** my actions in each controller.

I created a test controller to test this.

```
<?php

Class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    function indexAction() {
        echo "Index"; exit();
    }

    function testAction() {
        echo "Test"; exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Only the index action works. Test action does not work (throws EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION exception)

Zend Framework version - 1.12.0

Comment: What's up Lenin? =) Post your routes config too, all definitions.

Comment: Hey @Keyne, Good to see you.. I am not adding any routes.. I am expecting the default controller/action route to work..

Comment: You get the wrong controller/action in an common request? Didn't get the part of REST/AJAX stuff. IIRC, you're saying that it doesn't work at all, even removing the ajax... Would your question simply be: *Default router not working*?

Comment: @Keyne, Exactly.. the default router isnt working.. checked with a TestController.. only the index action works.. test action isnt working.. edited my code..

Comment: Isn't there a Zend_Rest route in your Bootstrap? Or maybe a special route in the of preDispatch one your plugins?

Comment: @BasvanDorst You are AWESOME. I copied my bootstrap code from another project, which had the Zend Rest Route - I forgot to remove that. Removed it now - default router works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question (Actual answer is in the comment by Bas van Dorst)

There was a Zend_Rest_Route code in the bootstrap, which I forgot to remove from an old code.
After the removing that code, default routes started working.

Comment: Do you know if is possible to have MVC and REST rules applied in the same application? I have tried to configure one specific module rule as REST but all the modules rules end working as REST.